# OpenCV Error: Assertion

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

```
Mat m1 = Mat(500, 300, CV_64F, Vec3b(255,255,255));
  for (int i = 0; i < m1.rows; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < m1.cols; ++j)
    {
        Vec3b color=m1.at<Vec3b>(Point(i, j));
    }
imshow("test2", m1);
waitKey();
```

The variable color should contain the color of the pixel which is white but i when i run the code i get the error:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (((((sizeof(size_t)<<28)|0x8442211) >>
>   ((traits::Depth<_Tp>::value) & ((1 << 3) - 1))*4) & 15) ==
>   elemSize1()) in cv::Mat::at, file
>   c:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp, line 1118

Comment: The data type of `Mat` should be `CV_8UC3` instead of `CV_64F`. Also, the  coordinates should be `Point(j, i)` instead of `Point(i, j)`.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you what you need to know. You've gone out of bounds!

Try:

```
Point(j, i)
```

Columns correspond to `x`. Rows correspond to `y`.

Comment: I haven't used OpenCV in a while. Try using `Mat_` instead. Also, try `Vec3b color=m1.at<Vec3b>(i, j);`

Comment: Visual studio doesn't recognize Mat_ and i did try using m1.at<Vec3b>(j, i); and it doesn't work

Comment: @BahiAli You need to use the same type of data, now you have matrix of one channel with doubles and you try to access it as if it was a matrix of 3 channels and uchar. either you change CV_64F to CV_8UC3 or you change all the Vec3b to double

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
Mat m1 = Mat(500, 300, CV_64F, Vec3b(255,255,255));
  for (int i = 0; i < m1.rows; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < m1.cols; ++j)
    {
        Vec3b color=m1.at<Vec3b>(i, j);//changed
    }
imshow("test2", m1);
waitKey();
```